# snake game in javascript with an Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript

In my code there's a line

```
if (nx== -1 || nx ==w/cw || ny==-1 || ny=h/cw || check_collision(nx,ny,snake_array)) {
```

JavaScript says `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in an assignment`. How do I fix this?

Comment: The error message is quite clear... and what does this have to do with notepad anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `=` after `ny`:

```
if (nx == -1 || nx == w/cw || ny == -1 || ny == h/cw || check_collision(nx, ny, snake_array)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough, the expression

```
nx== -1 || nx ==w/cw || ny==-1 || ny=h/cw
```

does not only contain a typo (you probably wanted `ny==h/cw`) but also creates a syntax error due to the order of operations: if you put

```
nx== -1 || nx ==w/cw || ny==-1 || (ny=h/cw)
```

instead, your error will be gone but the initial expression is not valid since it is read (pseudocode):

```
calc nx== -1 || nx ==w/cw || ny==-1 || ny // gives a number, say 10
set the result to h/cw // same as 10 = h/cw which is not a valid expression
```

And this "issue" gives you a hint that there's a problem with the operator you used.